# Can somebody translate this seal script, please?

Tags: seal, transliteration

I am researching about a Chinese poet who wrote in Spanish as "A. Kuan Veng". This is surely an approximation of his name in Spanish, however, in his seal appear four characters: I am pretty sure three of them are: 關, 景 and 南
I would be deeply thankful if you give me the last character, and also a possible dialect for the writer, since Mandarin 關 /guān/ is almost a perfect phonological match with the Spanish pronunciation of "Kuan", but Mandarin 景 /jǐng/ and /nán/ do not start with a /a/ vowel sound nor are similar to "Veng".

Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: most likely, such style of romanisation is from macau. kuan —> 關, veng -> 永

Comment: I’m Jk from Hong Kong. And I’m searching for something important about the name of the seal. May I have a talk with you through email? Thanks a lot. And you may help a lot on the story of the seal. Hope you may contact me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last character is 印

[image]

The seal read 關景南印 (Guan Jingnan's seal). 關景南 is the author's name

(originally I thought it was '色' [image] in "景色" which means "scenery" (they do look similar to me)

Comment: i would say it’s “關景南印”, with “景南” as given name. 

Comment: Thanks.  I thought it was 色  in 景色 (they do look similar to me)

Comment: yes, the 刀 and 爪 is quite similar in seal script 

Comment: Thank you very much. Please, help me about the transliteration: "Kuan" is fine, sounds almost the same in Spanish, but I cannot understand how “景南” can become "A...". Also, as a previous commenter stated, probably is Macanese romanization (makes sense since Spanish and Portuguese are almost the same). Maybe "Veng" (永) was the maid name of his mother? In Spanish, his given name is "A...", "Kuan" the paternal surname, and the name after it should be the mother's surname. Since he wrote in Spanish, lived in a Spanish-speaking country, is this plausible? Thanks!

Comment: TL;DR I cannot get the name, but I am pretty sure "Veng" stands for the mother's family name, included to conform to Hispanic custom.
Also, I would be grateful if you give me your names so I can thank you in my publication, when it gets out.